# How can I create a cylinder linking two points with Python?

Tags: python, modeling

I want to position a cylinder such that the center of one end is at `(x0, y0, z0)` and the center of the other end is at `(x1, y1, z1)` using the Python API.

The intention is that there will be **two spheres centered at those coordinates and the cylinder will act as a spoke or connector between them**.

I guess I will create the cylinder then translate, scale, rotate it. I am struggling mainly with the rotate part.

Comment: Could you provide a sketch with cylinder and spheres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a curve to join them together.

```
import bpy

# add sphere1
bpy.ops.surface.primitive_nurbs_surface_sphere_add(radius=.5, location=(-1, -1, 0))

# add sphere2
bpy.ops.surface.primitive_nurbs_surface_sphere_add(radius=.5, location=(1, 1, 0))

# add a curve to link them together
bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_curve_add()
obj = bpy.context.object
obj.data.dimensions = '3D'
obj.data.fill_mode = 'FULL'
obj.data.bevel_depth = 0.1
obj.data.bevel_resolution = 4
# set first point to centre of sphere1
obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0].co = (-1,-1,0)
obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0].handle_left_type = 'VECTOR'
# set second point to centre of sphere2
obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1].co = (1,1,0)
obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1].handle_left_type = 'VECTOR'
```

Answer (score 23):

i wrote my own script, as there is no way to do it with blender API direcly:

```
def cylinder_between(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, r):

  dx = x2 - x1
  dy = y2 - y1
  dz = z2 - z1    
  dist = math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)

  bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
      radius = r, 
      depth = dist,
      location = (dx/2 + x1, dy/2 + y1, dz/2 + z1)   
  ) 

  phi = math.atan2(dy, dx) 
  theta = math.acos(dz/dist) 

  bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[1] = theta 
  bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[2] = phi
```

enjoy :-)

Answer (score 3):

#### UI

A really fast way to do this is to make an *Mesh object* which is based on an edge-net (just edges), then in Object mode press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to convert to Curve, then use a bevel object or increase the bevel_depth + bevel_resolution

#### python

here's how to generate one *Curve object*, to hold all segments. It works on the idea that you have a *Mesh object* called 'EdgesObject', which just contains a collection of edges. Then you run the script and it will generate a new *Curve object* called 'TubesCurve'

[image]

```
import bpy

curves = bpy.data.curves
objects = bpy.data.objects
scene = bpy.context.scene

obj_name = "EdgesObject"
obj = objects[obj_name]

def make_tubes(obj, bevel_depth=0.1, resolution=3):

    mesh = obj.data
    curve_name = 'TubesCurve'

    # if exists, pick up else generate a new one
    cu = curves.get(curve_name, curves.new(name=curve_name, type='CURVE'))
    cu.dimensions = '3D'
    cu.fill_mode = 'FULL'
    cu.bevel_depth = bevel_depth
    cu.bevel_resolution = resolution
    cu_obj = objects.get(curve_name, objects.new(curve_name, cu))

    # break down existing splines entirely.
    if cu.splines:
        cu.splines.clear()

    # and rebuild
    verts = mesh.vertices
    for e in mesh.edges:
        idx_v1, idx_v2 = e.vertices
        v0, v1 = verts[idx_v1].co, verts[idx_v2].co
        full_flat = [v0[0], v0[1], v0[2], 0.0, v1[0], v1[1], v1[2], 0.0]

        # each spline has a default first coordinate but we need two.
        segment = cu.splines.new('POLY')
        segment.points.add(1)
        segment.points.foreach_set('co', full_flat)

    if not curve_name in scene.objects:
        scene.objects.link(cu_obj)  


make_tubes(obj)
```

The script will reuse an existing instance of the 'TubesCurve' object if the script is run repeatedly.

#### cons

If you need the cylinders to be capped, then it is necessary to use a bevel object, else that option (may 2015) is not available).

Answer (score 0):

Considering `Cylinder` API document: `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices=32, radius=1.0, depth=2.0, end_fill_type='NGON', view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), layers=(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))` apparently there is no way to construct what you want directly using cylinder parameters because there is only one point as the centre point (location) not endpoints.

**solution 1)** You will need to find rotations for rotation parameter of cylinder. If you have them you just simply set the location of cylinder as centre of your endpoints; set rotation values; the depth will be the distance between the endpoints.

**solution 2)** However, you may simply draw a line between the endpoints and apply blending. It will be a cylinder.

```
bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_circle_add()    #for blending
obj = bpy.context.object
bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_curve_add()     # a curve, your endpoints for example
bpy.context.object.data.bevel_object = bpy.data.objects[obj.name] #a cylinder
```

Answer (score 0):

modified script from @CyberBunny, which uses bmesh:

```py
def addConeBetweenPoints(v1: Vector, v2: Vector, r1 = 10, r2 = 0,
     name = "debugCone", collection: bpy.types.Collection = None):
  if not collection:
    collection = bpy.data.collections["Collection 0"]
  dv: Vector = v2 - v1
  bm = bmesh.new()
  bmesh.ops.create_cone(bm, cap_ends=True, cap_tris=False, segments=12,
                        radius1=r1, radius2=r2, depth=dv.length)
  debugMesh = bpy.data.meshes.new( name )
  bm.to_mesh(debugMesh)
  debugMeshObj = bpy.data.objects.new( name, debugMesh )
  debugMeshObj.display_type = "WIRE"
  collection.objects.link(debugMeshObj)
  
  debugMeshObj.location = v1 + dv/2
  debugMeshObj.rotation_mode = "QUATERNION"
  debugMeshObj.rotation_quaternion = Vector((0,0,1)).rotation_difference(dv)
```

In order to create a cylinder set `r2` to the same value as `r1`.