# How can I make a glowing material?

Tags: camera, light, wireframe

I asked related to this question in the past.  [How best to render a 3D grid?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84871/how-best-to-render-a-3d-grid)

Now I wanted to know how to make this picture in the blender.

[image]

Comment: And you have an answer there from mr.aradito as far as I can see. For glowing effect add Emission shader and Glow in Composite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glow with depth in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender) Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/how-to-make-edge-glow Or just type 'glow' in search box to see another results.

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71385/volumetric-windows-10-logo-effect