# How to draw a graph tree?

Tags: mesh, network

I am simulating some [abstract trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) (not plants) and would like to render them on blender.

My original thought was to draw a path using the API and then somehow give it a volume. Unfortunately I found that vertexes from a path (bezier or nurbs curve too) can only have a parent and a child. There is no option for bifurcation or at least I could not implement it.

I later found that a mesh vertices can indeed connect to many others after extruding many vertices from the same parent. This could work!

My train of thoughts was

1) simulate a tree and create a empty mesh
2) give x,y,z coords to each node and implement it as a vertex
3) connect the vertices accordingly
4) apply the Wireframe modifier to the mesh
5) finish

On manual tests, after extruding vertices one by one (see image). The Wireframe modifier doesn't apply "volume" to the mesh.

What am I missing here? Is the fact that there is not face between he edges of the mesh the problem? As a control I 'closed' the mesh by applying the 'convex hull' function - the wireframe modifier worked, but of course with an undesired product (see update below).

How would you proceed on this problem?

[image: hand drawn tree]

[image: wrong product]

Update:

I've managed to find an alternative that works for the time being. Applying a 'skin modifier' and re-scaling the mesh by selecting all vertices on edit mode gives some good-enough results.
[image]

I am still happy to learn more elegant solutions.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114348/space-colonization-tree/114371#114371)  Can adjust the radius of the wireframe modifier on a per original vertex basis.  IMO the way to go would be a bmesh script that extrudes a ring from node to node. Generating an N branch with nice topology (which you don't really get with wireframe mod in some cases)   is going to be the tricky bit.

Comment: Great - I just got started with bmesh. It already feels much flexible and less hacky than my first attempt. Will dig on that. Thanks